# Hex to decimal conversion with nan values

Tags: python, pandas, type-conversion, hex, try-catch

I am trying to convert a Pandas dataframe column `data['hexValues']` consisting of hex values to decimal.

```py
data["decValues"] = data.apply(lambda row: int(str(row["hexValues"]), 16), axis=1)
```

This works but the column `hexValues` look like this

```py
0       FF
1        F
2      nan
3      nan
4     FFFF
5     FFFF
6        F
7        F
8        F
9        F
10      FF
11     nan
12     nan
```

I want to skip `nan` values, so if the value is `nan`, no conversion will take place. I thought of using `try-except-else` but I am not sure how I can do it. Can you help me?

Comment: Can you try `data["decValues"] = data.apply(lambda row: int(str(row["hexValues"]), 16) if not pd.isnull(row["hexValues"]) else np.nan, axis=1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `nan`s are missing values use:

```
data["decValues"] = [int(x, 16) if pd.notna(x) else np.nan for x in data["hexValues"]]
```

More general solution with `try-except`:

```
def test(x):
    try:
        return int(x, 16)
    except ValueError:
        return np.nan

data["decValues"] = data["hexValues"].apply(test)
```

Comment: Tried and got the error
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 16: 'nan'

Comment: Thanks! I cannot upvote your answer but it worked!

Comment: Just curious ... Why `str(x)`?  Isn't `x` already a string or some type of `NaN`?

Comment: @rickhg12hs - good point, reason was because OP solution, answer was changed.

Answer (score 1):

Another option might be to use [`pandas.Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) since it has *built-in* `na_action`.

```python
data["decValues"] = data["hexValues"].map(lambda hexStr: int(hexStr, 16), na_action="ignore")
```

`na` values should just pass through without even calling the `map` function.